# Code::blocks 13.12 Dynamic Link Library support

Tags: c++, ubuntu, codeblocks

I am trying to build an export library (Win32 dll) using Code::Blocks running the GNU GCC compiler but the IDE does not have the dynamic link library in the File>New>Projects dialogue.

Any ideas on how to access this?

Thanks.

Comment: Figure out how to do it with the command line tools. That involves actually doing it. Then configure your IDE project to do the same.

Comment: I did the command line compile and using the IDE. The resulting Shared_object.so file is 2 Mb in size. As you can see the source code files are not small in size. I need the option to build .dll files using IDE so any errors and warnings are easier to debug as opposed to command line which will not display the errors in a logical manner.